# How to call the rest service in GXT?

Tags: xml, gxt

I am new to GXT, and now I have a backend which exposed as REST services. I can do get/post/put/delete regarding those REST services.

My question is: Which is the best way to use those REST services from GXT?

I do see that GXT official site tells that GXT support REST, while from their demo, I only see samples like xml grid, json grid, which only read from xml, json...

I want also can do update/delete/add actions...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this is quite a typical problem in GXT (ext-gwt), hopefully some one can help, thanks in advance~

Comment: urgent help is needed, any one could please kindly help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What would you consider to be the difference between a HTTP GET that retrieves JSON/XML, and subsequent POSTs or PUTs to save changes? The examples with HttpProxy allow you to set the url and the method used to get the data from the server, and subsequent RequestBuilders can be made to send data back to the server again.

REST is more about how you send data than the format of the data - I know of no reason that xml/json can't be used to talk to a rest-ful http server.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? GWT is a compiler/runtime, REST is a way to describe how state is shared or changed. GXT adds a few things to this mix to standardize how data is managed once it is in the app, and HttpProxy is one of the ways you can bring data into this system. HttpProxy can be told to GET/POST/PUT/DELETE any url (with some optional data), and can pass the results of that call on to the app, no matter what format it is in. What more is there? How is XML or JSON not a format that can be used with a RESTful system?